# Toyota corolla 2015 tyre upsize

Tags: toyota, tires, car, wheels

I have Toyota corolla 2015 with 17" rims.
The recommended tyre size is 215/45 r17, but I live in an area where there are a lot of pits on the roads.
Can I go with 215/50 r17, and how much will affect the

1. Acceleration
2. Fuel Efficiency
3. Car Handling
4. Mechanical wheel echo system on pits and bumps.

If anyone has an experience with similar upsizing it will be great to share his experience.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can most likely put the tire onto the rim and it will function just fine, all three of the areas you listed (acceleration, fuel efficiency, and car handling) will most likely suffer due to the new tires. Most likely, they'll only suffer somewhat to almost negligible, but they'll all suffer. The reason being is, the tire will be taller.

1. Acceleration - Since the tire will be taller, this extra height will mean the rolling radius will be longer, which in turn affects how power is applied. With the same amount of power coming from the engine, something has to give, which is the acceleration.
2. Fuel Efficiency - Since the tire is taller, it'll take more energy to get the same amount of mass moving, which means your fuel efficiency will suffer in around town driving. The engine will see reduced RPMs during highway travel, so if you're doing a lot of this type of driving, you may see a bit better fuel mileage here.
3. Car Handling - Usually with taller tires on the same sized rim you have taller sidewalls. Usually taller side walls means the tire is more "squishy", which means handling will be affected. This isn't *always* the case as it depends on the tire.

The other thing which will happen is your speedometer calibration will be off. Because the tire is taller, it will read slower than what your actual speed is.

If you can live with these tradeoffs, it may work out okay for you. Please realize, depending on where you take it to, some tire shops won't even allow you to change the tire size like this, so you may be out of luck all together.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seams like going  to 215/50 r17 is more suitable compering with 225/50 r17.
Does the up-sizing from 215/45 r17 to 215/50 r17 will affect the mechanical parts of the wheels echo system while passing the bumps or pits.

Comment: Could also consider dropping to a r16 rim, giving you are little more space for a larger tire height say 55. Would get a little more tire and similar height. Depends on budget of course.

Comment: @MohammadHarissa - Not sure what you're asking? If I'm understanding what you're asking, putting the larger tire on the same wheel should have no affect on the mechanical aspect of the vehicle. Having the larger sidewall should improve how it deals with the bumps/pits, but again, only marginally. There will be a little difference in the sidewall height, but not very much.

Comment: Think OP is asking if the increase in tire size will result in the tire scraping on the wheel well, or suspension parts, when doing over bumps, during turns, etc. If you have reasonable space now, an extra 2 inchs  you are probably fine. If you currently see any space with only an inch, probably going to touch. Pics of a stock car looks like up-down would be okay, but steering looks tight